# list search in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list in my C# web-application. this list is fill with keywords fetch from database.
Now i want to search in the list , as i have **mulitliple keyword search.**

if a **person type in blue** so all the record matching blue are fetched into the list. now when he type in **2nd keyword suppose yellow** so the list should be filtered and it must contain only those records which having blue and yellow and same is for **3rd and fourth key word.**

here is the code now what i have to do next ?

```
public override List<ThumbNail> GetSearchResults(string search1, string path)
        {
  List<ThumbNail> mylist = new List<ThumbNail>();
       if (search1.Length - 1 == search1.LastIndexOf(","))
       search1 = search.Remove(search1.Length - 1);     
  List<string> search = new List<string>(search1.Split(','));
    for(int i=0; i <search1.Count;i++)

{
      OleDbCommand sqlcmdCommand1 = 
      new OleDbCommand("select Name,File,keyword from table1 where keyword like @searchone", mycon);

 sqlcmdCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("searchone", search[i]);
 sqlcmdCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 OleDbDataReader sdaResult = sqlcmdCommand1.ExecuteReader();
 while (sdaResult.Read())
 {
  mytable thmb = new Thumbl();
  thmb.Name = sdaResult.GetString(0);
  thmbN.File = sdaResult.GetString(1);
  thmb.keyword = sdaResult.IsDBNull(3) ? "" : sdaResult.GetString(6);
  mylist.Add(thmb);
 }
```

}
     sdaResult.Close();

```
return mylist;
}

public class Thumbnail
{

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string File { get; set; }
        public string keyword { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
   }
```

this action is performed when user type in first keyword. and all the records matching first keyword are now in mylist, now when user type in second keyword so a search must be performed on list which match the first and 2nd keyword and the result is returned.

```
The DB table look like this:

id   name   keyword  File  Fkey
1     a      yellow  c:/   20
2     a      blue    c:/   20
3     a      Pinky   c:/   20
4     b      orange  c:/   21
5     b      Redish  c:/   21
```

Comment: How are the keywords stored in your DB? -- Btw., doing a `SELECT *` is a bad idea; since you already expect 5 specific columns to be returned, why not explicitly state them in the query (`SELECT Name, File, Path, Address, AlternateAddress WHERE ...`) so that they correspond with your calls to `sdaResult.GetString`?

Comment: @stakx I have edited the answer you can see and also have the DB structure:)

Comment: As far as I can see, your DB tables are not normalized (if `name` always references the same `file`). The correct way would be to have two tables `A = (id, name, file)` and `B = (id, keyword)`, linked by id. So, in your case, that would be `A = (1, a, c:/), (2, b, c:/)` and `B = (1, yellow), (1, blue), (1, Pinky), (2, orange), (2, Redish)`.

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks for this, Also if you can tell me how to do thing now on the front end as i will do this normalization now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: After you updated your question, my answer no longer applies, since your table structure is different than what I expected. My answer would work if your table looked like this:

```
id   name   keywords            File 
1     a     yellow blue pinky   c:/  
2     b     orange reddish      c:/
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**: First, you need to select the keywords as well, so that you can do further filtering.

```
thmb.Keywords = sdaResult.GetString(someIndex);
```

Then, you can use LINQ to create a filtered version of your list...

```
var filtered = mylist.Where(thmb => thmb.Keywords.Contains(search2));
```

...which you can filter further, as soon as new search keywords are entered.

```
var filtered = filtered.Where(thmb => thmb.Keywords.Contains(search3));
```

`filtered` is an `IEnumerable`. If you need a list, apply `.ToList()` to it.

---

**NEW ANSWER**: Basically, what you need to do with your table structure is to:

1. Make a second fetch from the database, making a list of names that contain the second keyword and
2. remove all list entries of your first list that are not contained in the second list. For example, if your list of names containing the second keyword is a `List<string>` called `narrowingSearch`, then you could do

   ```
   var filteredList = mylist.Where(thmb => narrowingSearch.Contains(thmb.Name));
   ```

---

**EDIT**: Now that you have a common FK, you should be able to do this by using a more advanced SQL, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT name, file
  FROM table1
 WHERE keyword like @search0
   AND fk IN (SELECT fk FROM table1 WHERE keyword LIKE @search1)
   AND fk IN (SELECT fk FROM table1 WHERE keyword LIKE @search2)
   ...
```

You can construct this SQL in a loop like this:

```
string[] search = search1.Split(',');

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT name, file FROM table1 WHERE keyword LIKE @search0", mycon);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search0", search[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < search.Length; i++) {
    cmd.CommandText += " AND fk IN (SELECT fk FROM table1 WHERE keyword LIKE @search" + i.ToString() + ")";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search" + i.ToString(), search[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Heinzi can i use like this  `var filtered = mylist.Where(thmb => thmb.Keywords.Contains(a[0]));` ? also can you forward a link for a tutorial like this :)

Comment: @Heinzi I do not get you, can you send me a link where i can fully follow and know what do to in order to get the result. Thanks

Comment: @safi: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @ heinzi `var filtered = mylist.Where(thmb => thmb.Keywords.Contains(search2));` when i typed in this, it says a local variable with the same name? also you say another query to databse so i have to write another query mentioning the search2 in the query? also narrowingSearch i didnt get this

Comment: @safi: OK, let's forget about C# for a moment. Do you understand how you would solve this problem from an algorithmic point of view?

Comment: @Heinzi i am confuse how to make this an algorithmic logic,its some thing in my mind is right but to make a logic to work in real is hard, so i do not understand clearly.

Comment: @safi: OK. Have a look at the part labeled "NEW ANSWER" in my answer (and forget about the code line in the end for a moment). Is it clear what I mean and do you understand why this would solve your problem?

Comment: @Heinzi, well i will make a second query on the database for search2,but how to remove them i do not know,confused

Comment: @safi: The `Where` statement filters a list based on a certain predicate, here is the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx

Comment: @Heinzi I have now Fully modified the code and now can you let me know how to now do it :)

Comment: @safi: It looks like your code takes a comma-separated list as a parameter. Are these comma-separated values the `search1`, `search2` you are talking about? Currently, it seems like your code returns all entries containing search[0] OR search[1] ...

Comment: @Heinzi. Yes the comma spearator does that as it recives the parameter and further it is process like search 1 or search2. yep this is the main problem as it return all the values. which i want to sort it out Thanks

Comment: @safi: You can solve this problem in your SQL: Instead of `where keyword LIKE @searchone`, create the command like this: `where keyword LIKE @search1 and keyword LIKE @search2 and ...`.

Comment: @Hinzi but this where like will limit the number of type in search by a user ? or is there any way to add dynmic to sql stmt?

Comment: @safi: Sure, since the sql stmt is just a string, you can just use a loop and string concatenation. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: @safi: Actually, I just realized that this won't work for you, since you have a different table structure. :-( You can do the following: In the first iteration of your loop (first search keyword), add the elements to mylist. In the next iterations, don't add the items but *remove* all those that do not match the newly selected keywords.

Comment: @Heinzi, I agree with you, How to remove them on the 2nd iteration?if you can modify your answer now?

Comment: @Heinzi i have linked the table with another table which is primary and it has now the foreigen KEY you can see it as i have updated the question